# mysql Procedure not returning any row

Tags: mysql, procedure

Why mysql query executes successfully after I create and execute the procedure and fill the  returns 0 row affected can it be because of group that is a pre reserved word ?

```
    CREATE
PROCEDURE getNamesFrmAllSchedCol(IN p_schedule_id INT(11))
SELECT g.group, h.hall, l.lush, u.user, s.subject
FROM
  scheduler sch
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.group_id=sch.group_id
INNER JOIN halls h ON h.hall_id=sch.hall_id
INNER JOIN lush l ON l.lush_id=sch.lush_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id=sch.user_id
INNER JOIN subjects s ON s.subject_id=sch.subject_id
WHERE
  sch.schedule_id = p_schedule_id
```

[When executing created procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwAeC.jpg)

[After executing returns 0 rows while it should return 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNHJC.jpg)

Comment: Look at your results again.  The procedure *does* return 1 row.  It *affects* (modifies) none but it *returns* 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because u.user did not exist the column in users was named username. Sorry for the lack of information.

Answer (score 0):

Affected_rows does not apply to select; applies to update, insert, delete